# defining class in javascript after ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax

when I create html with javascript after ajax response class "navtex-message" doesn't work.

```
function formatNtxMessage( m ) {
    return '<div class="row">' +
        '<div class="col-lg-9">' +
            '<div class="navtex-message">' +
                JSON.stringify(m.content).replace(/\"/g, "")  + 
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +          
    '</div>';
}

function format ( d ) {
    var div = $('<div/>')
     .addClass( 'loading' )
     .text( 'Učitavanje...' );

     $.ajax( {
         type: "GET",
         url: '/api/ntxMessage/' + d.id,
         success: function ( json ) {
             div
                 .html(formatNtxMessage(json.data))
                 .removeClass( 'loading' );
         }
     } );

    return div;
}
```

Class navtex-message make in text new line instead \r\n:

```
.navtex-message {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

String that I get:

```
ZCZC QE02\r\n050640 UTC MAR\r\n\r\nSPLIT RADIO\r\n\r\nWEATHER BULLETIN FOR ADRIATIC\r\n\r\nISSUED BY THE MARINE METEOROLOGICAL CENTER SPLIT ON 05/03/2018 AT 0400 UTC\r\n\r\n1. WARNING:\r\n\r\nISOLATED GUST OF SE / NE WIND, IN THE EVENING NW 35-45 KTS, IN VELEBIT STRATE NW TO 55 KTS. POSSIBLE SUDDEN STORMS. \r\n\r\n2. SYNOPSIS:\r\n\r\nTROUGH WITH FRONTAL DISTURBANCE APPROACHED TOWARD ADRIATIC FM THE WEST.\r\n\r\n3. FORECAST FOR THE NEXT 24 HOURS VALID UNTIL 06/03/2018. AT 0400 UTC\r\n\r\nN-ERN ADRIATIC:\r\n\r\nNE, OFFSHORE AT FIRST SE, IN THE EVENING AND OVERNIGHT NW INCREASING ON 12-24, IN VELEBIT STRATE TO 30 KTS. TOMORROW NE / NW WIND DECREASING ON 4-12 KTS. SEA INCREASING ON 3-4, TOMORROW DECREASING ON 2-3. VSBY 10-20 KM. MOSTLY CLOUDY WITH RAIN, POSSIBLE THUNDERSHOWERS.\r\n\r\nCENT ADRIATIC:\r\n\r\nSE INCREASING ON 15-30, OVERNIGH TURNING ON NW 12-24 KTS, TOMORROW DECREASING ON 4-12 KTS. ALONG THE COAST LOCALLY E / NE 6-16 KTS, MOSTLY ON N-ERN PART.SEA 2-3, INCREASING ON 3-4, TOMORROW DECREASING ON 2-3. VSBY 10-20 KM. MOSTLY CLOUDY WITH RAIN, POSSIBLE THUNDERSHOWERS.\r\n\r\nS-ERN ADRIATIC:\r\n\r\nSE WIND INCREASING ON 16-32, OVERNIGHT TURNING ON NW 12-24 KTS, TOMORROE DECREASING AND TURNING ON SW 4-14, ON FAR OF SOUTH TO 18 KTS. ALONG THE COAST LOCALLY E / NE 6-16, ON FAR OF SOUTH TO 20 KTS. SEA 2-3, INCREASING ON 3-4, TOMORROW DECREASING ON 2-3. VSBY 10-20 KM. MOSTLY CLOUDY WITH RAIN, POSSIBLE THUNDERSHOWERS.\r\n\r\n\r\nNNNN\r\n\r\n
```

What I'm doing wrong to get line break instead \r\n?

Comment: Have you inspected your code after ajax? Maybe style is wrong or there is no new lines in code?

Comment: Check the console please and also consider using $(window).on("load", function () {});.

Comment: This is string after JSON.stringify: ZCZC QE02\r\n050640 UTC MAR\r\n\r\nSPLIT RADIO\r\n\r\nWEATHER BULLETIN FOR ADRIATIC\r\n      I want to \r\n be shown as new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved problem:

```
function formatNtxMessage( m ) {
return '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-lg-9">' +
        '<div class="navtex-message">' +
            m.content + 
        '</div>' +
    '</div>' +          
'</div>';
}
```

Problem was that m.content is string value from json. :)
Thanks on your help.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify()` converts your `m.content` to single-lined json.

So there will be no effect for `white-space: pre-line`.

Add [third param](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Syntax) (number of spaces) to stringify in order to *pretty print*

```js
$('pre').html(
  JSON.stringify({'a': 1, 'b': 'c'}, null, 4)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```